# iPhone + cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am using UITableView in my application. I am using the cellForRowAtIndexPath method of the UITableView control.

My question is that why this method cellForRowAtIndexPath is called whenever I scroll the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the visible cells are requested.  If you scroll the table, it will generate the new ones that come into view...

Comment: Thanks, but if I want to generate all the cells at once for the table?

Comment: What do you need that for? Existing approach (and reusing cells) is a great optimization really.

Comment: If you want to build your table information once, then I suggest you build a data structure to hold the information you need, then look it up when the table cell comes into view.  Put it in an NSDictionary, or whatever...